# Is it possible to restore from Time Machine backup if there is no OS installed on main drive

Tags: macos

The question title says it all, really. I upgraded my SSD and now I don't have a disk to boot from except OS X Recovery. I have both Internet connection and a USB drive from which I can install a clean copy but I would prefer not doing so unless it is necessary because that usually takes a lot of time. When I try restoring from a Time Machine backup it says "Searching for Time Machine backups..." although my backup drive is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible via recovery (Hold during startup <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>). If you can't find a Time Machine backup in recovery, try holding <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> during startup and after that choose Time Machine drive.

Comment: Neither Recovery nor Time Machine shows any of my backups.